# How to schedule task with custom date in Windows server 2003?

Tags: windows-server-2003, scheduled-tasks

I want schedule the task to run every 9th, 19th, 23rd, 30th, 6th of a month. However the task scheduler wizard only has the options of daily, weekly, monthly and just once. Can I create the task from command line?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a task with multiple triggers in the GUI.

The command line tool schtasks.exe can create tasks also.

To do multiple triggers you should create it in the gui first and export it as an XML. After that you can import the XML on another computer using *schtasks /XML*. I'm not sure it can be done in W2K3 though. You should test this.